# what is the best way to create new password?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, forgot-password

I have built mvc 3 application where I trying to built the forgot password functionality.The process are following.

- At first user will be prompt to enter the username
- If username exist the security question is shown
- If user enter the correct answer the newly created password will be
  sent to the email that is saved in database at the time of the
  registration

here I have completed upto the second steps and also completed the checking answer. What I want to know is what may be best way to create the new password which will sent to the email. I have searched for creating random string and found this..

```
var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
var random = new Random();
var result = new string(
    Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 8)
              .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
              .ToArray());
```

I think but not sure there may be chance to create again same random string so may not be suitable for new password. what can be best way to generate new password. Any help please will be appreciated. thank you!

Comment: Troy Hunt wrote an extensive blog post about password resets: [Everything you ever wanted to know about building a secure password reset feature](http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/05/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know.html)

Comment: Do you mean this is a temp password and he will have to change it on first login ?

Comment: ya this may be temp password and user have change password functionality after login with new password

Comment: Please don't send a password, just email a reset link.

Comment: I have never built the reset password functionality by using reset link, would you please provide link or explain the steps.

Comment: @Erno What's the difference? Emailing a link with a unique id built in, or emailing a link and a password. The only difference I see is that emailing a temp password is quicker to develop.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst - Please read the article Oded linked to. It contains a discussion on this.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the link provided by @Odded: would say that considering that it's better to use 
[SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) class when holding the password string in memory.

> Represents text that should be kept confidential. The text is
>   encrypted for privacy when being used, and deleted from computer
>   memory when no longer needed. This class cannot be inherited.

Cause some malitios software can dump your process memory in the moment of authentication, and in case of simple `string`, the *clear*  string will be accessible to the hacker.

Answer (score 0):

I would use  Guid.New(). But as it was said it's better to send the link to set new password

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Membership.GeneratePassword` method. You can find documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.generatepassword.aspx). This is a much more secure mechanism because they will use cryptography under the covers and you have some nice flexibility because it allows you to determine how long and how many alphanumeric characters to include. It generates some **strong** passwords, I've used it.

Answer (score 0):

For the forget password use this:

```
string username = member.LogName;
                    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(username);
                    string generatedPassword = user.ResetPassword();
                    mail(generatedPassword ); // create custom function to mail the new
```

generated password.